# Accessing reference variable from shared_ptr

Tags: shared-ptr, make-shared

I wasn't sure about the title, so apologies in advance if it's not very clear.

The example below illustrates my problem.

When I use **new** to initialize the shared_ptr from the Member Initialization List then when I assign a value to the &ref_bar everything seems to work fine. However, when I try the same thing with **make_shared**, which is the preferred way, it doesn't work.

Can you please explain what happens under the hood for this to occur?

*Please ignore the "bad" coding in the following example. I've created this to illustrate my problem. I'm interested in what matters the shared_ptr.*

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Bar
{
   int m_bar;

   public:
      int &ref_bar;

      Bar(int bar_) : m_bar(bar_),ref_bar(m_bar)
      {;}
      void print()
      {
         std::cout<< "m_bar = "<<m_bar<<std::endl;
      }
};

struct Foo
{
   std::shared_ptr<Bar> m_foo;

   Foo() : m_foo( std::make_shared<Bar>(Bar(23)) )   // Ex.1
   //Foo() : m_foo( new Bar(23) )                    // Ex.2
   {
      m_foo->print();
      m_foo->ref_bar = 12;
      m_foo->print();
   }
};

int main()
{
   Foo f;
}
```

The results are:

```
Ex.1 >> 23,23   Wrong.
Ex.2 >> 23,12   Ok.
```

Here's a link to ideone: http://ideone.com/xluYQ9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed when changing the constructor from:

```
Foo() : m_foo( std::make_shared<Bar>(Bar(23)) )   // Ex.1
```

to

```
Foo() : m_foo( std::make_shared<Bar>(23) )   // Ex.1
```

There's something about calling the constructor inside the make_shared arguments. I still don't know why so if anyone knows more about this please do answer the question in detail.